# Is there a way to log read/write access to a specific column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, refactoring, refactoring-databases

Is there any way in MySQL to log any query that accesses a certain column in a table?

**Purpose:**
I need to do this for refactoring purposes - I have to change the structure of the database but because I was not smart enough at the time to use unique searchable column names it is now very difficult for me to locate ALL the places in my PHP code where I deal with that column. So if I could start logging all queries that access that column over time I could have a complete overview of exactly which queries use that column and therefore be able to modify my PHP code (assuming that all possible queries had been run some time in that period).

Comment: This could be done by defining a trigger on every table but it would be messy. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

While I wrote my misgivings below, this question relates to "auditing" and "logging".

Basic statement logging can achieved using the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) and more advanced auditing can be performed by the [Enterprise Audit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-enterprise-audit.html) plugin. Triggers are *not* appropriate for logging queries but have been known to implement update/insert change log trails.

---

I think that trying to find the usage programmatically is misguided. Refactoring is not an "ongoing" process - it's done once (per refactor goal) and life moves on. Tests (e.g. unit/integration) and code-coverage can tell the *results* of refactoring, but generally work best with a formalized [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)/API.

Instead, this is a good time to sit down with the code-base and carefully analyze all database access calls. Even a terrible column name like `id` is relatively easy to grep through files for if merely trying to find certain occurrences. Chances are it'll only require an hour or two to "feel comfortable" about the manual changes. Now, if only such changes could be tested ..

It would also be prudent to refactor all access out into named methods with well-defined contracts, which could later be pushed up into a proper DAL, even if they are currently left at the call-sites. This separation of concerns is the basis underpinning testability and future refactoring.

Comment: I understand refactoring is not an ongoing process but I don't see why logging over a certain period of time couldn't be feasible and helpful. It certainly could avoid a lot of bugs when the refactoring is done so I don't see why it wouldn't make a lot of sense to have such a feature. When you have a code base of 3-400.000 lines we are talking more than a couple of hours work to do it completely manually! Let the technology help us, that's what it is there for! I agree that unit tests, abstractions etc. are great ways to go - but more could be done.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder Not for refactoring. This is called "auditing" (e.g. [Enterprise Audit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-enterprise-audit.html])) and "logging" (e.g. [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html)).